# How to calculate the following sum?

Tags: summation

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{10000}{\left(2n+3\right)^4}$

I could only prove that it is convergent, but I have no idea how to find the sum.
Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Call $S$ the sum.

We know that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$$

Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n)^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{1440}$$

Therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}-\frac{\pi^4}{1440}=\frac{\pi^4}{96}$$

Thus,
$$S=10000\left(\frac{\pi^4}{96}-1-\frac1{81}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

First, you can ignore the factor 10000, it is only here for show. Then, write
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^4} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^4} = \frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^4} \\
&= \frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} + 1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+3)^4}
 = \frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} + 1 + \frac{1}{3^4} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+3)^4} 
\end{align}$$
so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+3)^4} = -1 -\frac{1}{81}+ \frac{15}{16} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}$. Can you compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}$?